# JS, Safari issue. range setStart & setEnd doesnt select and highlight a text of doesn`t contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript, html, range

I need to programatically select text of div.

```
function selectAndHighlightText(elementId) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);

    const range = new Range();
    range.setStart(element.firstChild, 10);
    range.setEnd(element.lastChild, 30);

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

this code will select text of div. The text will select just in Android and desltop but in IPhone doesnt selected text.
Android: In android devices i can with range setStart & setEnd.
andorid screenshot
[My web sait in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ech6.jpg).

Iphone safari screenshot:
[my web sait in safari Iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7he3.jpg).

How i can in Safari iphone too programmatically select the text.

Comment: Refer to https://caniuse.com/?search=window.getSelection to see compatibility, there is mixed support for iOS Safari for the code you wish to use